# SQL Server logs error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

There are two SQL Server 2012 instances on the server. Named instance gives following error when `Management > SQL Server Logs` is clicked. Default instance works OK and opens Log file viewer.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)
Standard Edition

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

Comment: What happens when you run `EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog` on the instance?

Comment: Msg 22004, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to open loopback connection. Please see event log for more information.
Msg 22004, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error log location not found.

Comment: I checked the value of SQL sever errorlog entry and it is correct.

Comment: When EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog is executed following message is recorded in application log. Login failed for user 'AD\user'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: IP].

Comment: SQL server service was restarted yesterday. It runs under 'AD\user' with correct password.

Comment: What is your connectivity settings like? Did you happen to shut down local connections?